# How to get the source code from a HttpClient HttpResponse?

Tags: java, httpclient, http-post, httpresponse

Here is my HttpClient request:

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.***.**/***/***_***.php");
        String HTML = "";
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("from", contactName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msg", message));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sent", time_sent));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HTML = "How?";

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {} catch (IOException e) {}
```

How can I fill the HTML string with the source code of the request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HTML = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Answer (score 4):

There you go:

```
String html = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString( response.getEntity() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the response html by reading the stream from the `httpresponse.getEntity().getContent();`

Somehow I think this might not answer your question because you use the word "source code".